# errors with the name of the table in Datamapper ( city )

Tags: php, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper, datamapper-1.2

I've a model called City in datamapper for codeigniter. I've kept the name of the table as "cities" because datamapper expects the name of the table in pluralized form. Now when I create the object for the model in controller ( $c = new City(); ); I get following error : Call to a member function where() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\project\application\controllers\userhome.php on line 61 .

This is the model I've used

```
                    <?php

        class City extends DataMapper {

            //var $table = "cities";
            function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
        }

        ?>
```

As you can see in the model that i've tried to assign the table name to the variable which for now I've commented. I got the error with that also.

These are the codes I am using in my controller.

```
                    $c = new City(); 

                    $details3 = $c -> where('city_id', $ct) -> get();
        foreach($details3 as $d3)
        {
            $data['city_native_from_city_table'] = $d3 -> city_name; 
        }
        echo $data['city_native_from_city_table']; echo "<br>";
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you can remove comment in code see below:

```
    <?php

        class City extends DataMapper {

            var $table = "cities";
            function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
        }

        ?>
```

and try again..!

Comment: First of all lot of thanks for the reply... I tried with that also but I still get the same error :(

Comment: can i see userhome.php file code? i want to see line number 61

Comment: This code $details3 = $c -> where('city_id', $ct) -> get(); which you can find above lies in 61st number line in my userhome.php file.

Comment: what does var_dump($c) tell you?